# How to get Riak KV cluster and node status data in Go

Tags: go, exec, riak, basho-client

I'm trying to monitor Riak-KV from Go program. Riak has a client for go named 'riak-go-client', But it doesn't have any api to get Riak performance/Status data.
Is there any way to get it ?

Comment: I have gone through riak docs but I didn't find any way to Get its status using Go program, they have provided CLI commands.

Comment: I'm not saying I want to read from command line tool But my question is what is possible(best) ways to read Riak Status ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get Riak performance/status/metrics might be via its [stats HTTP API](http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.2.3/developing/api/http/status/). It works with any language or even using `curl`. As long as you know how to connect via HTTP and parse JSON, you should be able to use it.

Using the API can be as simple as running:

`curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8098/stats -H "Accept: application/json"`

It gives you a lot of useful information like allocated and used memory, get/put statistics, CPU utilization, ring status, etc.

[Riak Explorer](https://github.com/basho-labs/riak_explorer) exposes an even more powerful API that allows not only to monitor, but also manage Riak clusters. You have to install the tool separately though.